# WSO2 - Fails to redirect after custom authentication endpoint POST

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have created an custom authentication endpoint, like https://www.custom-auth.localpc, which is being redirect to by WSO2 when i try to login.
However, when I click in OK and send the POST back to http://localhost:9443/commonauth, WSO2 replies with a 302 that redirects to http://localhost:9443/https://www.custom-auth.localpc?loginStatus=true.

When I checked the console log, I found the following error:

`ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Exception in Authentication Framework
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.FrameworkException: No authenticator can handle the request in step :  1`

The service provider that requests the login is correctly configured because it works with WSO2 default authentication endpoint.

Any thought on this?

Comment: Can you please enable debug logs as mentioned below and share the log.

Open up <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties file.
Uncomment below line
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework=DEBUG.
Restart Server.
Initiate the authentication flow.
Share the log in console or <IS_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue was quite simplier that I thought. The redirects from wso2 were more of a misdirection.

So, when submitting the data, the field `username` and `password` must be lowercase.

Any issue found with the post data, it redirects with a 302 to the carbon login page.

Comment: In my case,  I missed the "id" and "name" attribute on password field.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may happen because of the canHandle() method. you can refer [other](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+Clef+Authenticator) [custom authenticators](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS) which are using external endpoint and [try](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-clef/blob/master/component/org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/authenticator/clef/ClefAuthenticator.java#L73) these are how handle the request.

Comment: But I don't intend a different authentication system. I just want WSO2 with a customized page like in this link:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Customizing+Login+Pages+for+Service+Providers

Comment: when you post back to is you should set sessionDataKey in the request[1] and check whether is there any other parameters your checking in canHandle() methos
[1] https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-inwebo/blob/master/component/authentication-endpoint/src/main/webapp/inwebo.jsp#L135

Comment: Make sure to send back the "sessionDataKey" with the form submission, by using a hidden input field.
<input type="hidden" name="sessionDataKey" value="<%=request.getParameter("sessionDataKey")%>"/>